# Python enter a hidden password

Tags: python

I have a python script that I made to update and upgrade my Linux system, it is written in python but after I tell it to update it prompts me to enter a hidden password and I was wondering if there is a way to get Python to enter the hidden password for me. This is my code its simple and works I just need to know if there is a way to enter hidden passwords with python.

```
import os,sys
os.system("sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade")
```

Comment: Why bother using Python? You can just run a bash script with the `apt-get` commands.

Comment: stdlib: `getpass`. I'm pretty sure you didn't search anything...

Comment: Are you asking if you can get python to interrogate you for the password (`getpass`), or if you can get python to communicate a password to `sudo`?

Comment: Doukremt I meant in the script I want to to automatically enter the password when it prompts me for one but since the password is hidden by default on Linux I have struggled with just a simple print("password here")

Comment: Emmet I am asking if I can get a Python to communicate a password to sudo.

Comment: @Forge No, that’s not what your question is saying. If you want to communicate with another process, check out the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @Forge: then run your script with root privileges.

Comment: Don't automate password entry! If you want `sudo` to run without a password prompt, edit your `/etc/sudoers` file with `visudo` to grant your script permission to execute `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks you guys this all helped so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) module. Take a look at [this](http://mervine.net/executing-bash-from-python) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There is a std function in python for doing this. See [getpass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html)

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: Don't understand the downvote either. The author says "... I just need to know if there is a way to enter hidden passwords with python". That's what getpass does.